# Restore T-SQL Editing in VS2010 after SQL Server 2008 R2 install

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2008

I was able to edit Database projects in my installation of VS2010 ultimate. However per project requirements I had to uninstall SQL Server 2008 and install SQL Server 2008 R2. Now I have lost the ability to open sql files in VS2010 IDE. Whenever I double-click on a .sql file to open the script file, I get an "Object reference not set" error. Looks like the extension to edit SQL files in VS2010 has been removed.

How do I reinstall the T-SQL editor extension?

Have tried repairing both VS2010 and SQL Server 2010

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at this post

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vssetup/thread/27ef7c94-4410-4925-ab22-3fec475b1885

> To fix the issue of not being able to load the RadLangSvc.Package here is what you need to do:
>
> 1. Load up your ISO or DVD VS2010 Installer in an explorer window
> 2. Go to the WCU foldler
> 3. Go to the DAC folder
> 4. Install MSI's
>
>    i. DACFramework_enu.msi
>      ii. DACProjectSystemSetup_enu.msi
>      iii. TSqlLanguageService_enu.msi

Comment: Link-only posts are frown upon because they can go stale. You should copy the relevant parts just in case.

Answer (score 1):

Look for "Restore File Associations" under `Tools` > `Options` > `Environment`. I don't have VS in front of me but I've used that in the past.

Comment: unfortunately that did not fix the issue. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: In that case, though it's an extreme measure, I'd reinstall VS 2010 from scratch, like you did with SQL Server. Obviously there's some arcane magic Microsoft uses to associate .sql files with 2008 R2 :-).